# Is there a possibility to specify allure link pattern with two or more parameters?

Tags: allure

In allure its possible to set link pattern for @TmsLink annotation:

`allure.link.tms.pattern = https://prod.com/p/11707/sets/123456/instances/{}/edit`

And then in the test you can specify the instanceId using @TmsLink annotation:

```
    @TmsLink("88275899")
    @Test
    public void testCanLoginWithCorrectCred() {
        ///...some test code
    }
```

As a result you will get link in the following format:
`https://prod.com/p/11707/sets/123456/instances/88275899/edit`

The question is how to have two or more parameters in link pattern, I need something like:
`allure.link.tms.pattern = https://prod.com/p/{}/sets/{}/instances/{}/edit`

But how to set these parameters via annotation on test method?